# Is there a way to include TextViews in custom views in Android?

Tags: java, android

so I am trying to make a ListItem in an App that I am making, and I want it to look something like this:

[image]

When I hop into my layout.xml file, without the ListItem, the preview renders properly and so does the app.

[image][image]

However with the ListItem, the preview and app do not render.

[image][image]

The error was

```
Error inflating class ListItem
```

which was caused by

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

So it had to be something with the TextView.

Here is my code (I just removed all imports and constructors):

```java
public class ListItem extends View {

    private String subjectName;
    private int backgroundColor;
    TextView subjectNameTextView;

    public void setSubjectName() {
        if (this.subjectName != null) {
            subjectNameTextView.setText(this.subjectName);
        }
    }

    public void setColor() {
        if (this.backgroundColor != 0) {
            this.setBackgroundColor(this.backgroundColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `activity_maths.xml` if needed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MathsActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello!"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.atharvnadkarni.funlurn.ListItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:title="Text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Alright everyone, I found another post that said to do `addView` on a `ViewGroup`, so I changed my `setSubjectName` function to this:

```java
public class ListItem extends RelativeLayout {

    public void setSubjectName() {
        if (this.subjectName != null) {
            addView(subjectNameTextView);
            subjectNameTextView.setText(this.subjectName);
        }
}
}
```

But this does not work, and shows that you
`Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup`

Comment: Have you initialized the `TextView` you are using `setText()` on?

Comment: How am I supposed to initialize it? I don't have an Layout file for the ListItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the nullPointerException because you did not initialized you textview "subjectNameTextView". please change

```
public class ListItem extends View {

private String subjectName;
private int backgroundColor;
TextView subjectNameTextView;

public void setSubjectName() {
    if (this.subjectName != null) {
        subjectNameTextView.setText(this.subjectName);
    }
}

public void setColor() {
    if (this.backgroundColor != 0) {
        this.setBackgroundColor(this.backgroundColor);
    }
}
}
```

to

```
public class ListItem extends View {

private String subjectName;
private int backgroundColor;
TextView subjectNameTextView;

public void setSubjectName() {
 subjectNameTextView = new TextView(this); // this code you have to add
    if (this.subjectName != null) {
        subjectNameTextView.setText(this.subjectName);
    }
}

public void setColor() {
    if (this.backgroundColor != 0) {
        this.setBackgroundColor(this.backgroundColor);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This answer, together with David's answer, are not quite efficient, especially since you are going to use it in a list, judging by the class's name. The reason is that they instantiate `TextView` everytime you set the text. The best way to solve it is to instantiate the it in the `CONSTRUCTOR`, so you only do it once.

Comment: But @ndriqa which constructor?

Comment: I have a constructor with only `context`, one with `context` and `attrs`, and one with `context`,`attrs`, and `defStyleAttr`

Comment: Since your view AND the text view are both `View`s, you can init the `TextView` in each constructor, and pass all the parameters of each constructor, So, in the constructor with only `context` you init `subjectNameTextView = TextView(context)`, in the constructor with `context` and `attrs`, you init `subjectNameTextView = TextView(context, attrs)`, ...etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you do not initialize subjectNameTextView, so it is null. And after that, you are trying to call the textView's method on a null object reference.
Try doing this:

```
public class ListItem extends RelativeLayout {

    public void setSubjectName() {
        if (this.subjectName != null) {
            if (this.subjectNameTextView == null){
                this.subjectNameTextView = new TextView(context);
            }
            subjectNameTextView = new TextView(context);
            addView(subjectNameTextView);
            subjectNameTextView.setText(this.subjectName);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can put text view initialization into your constructor, but be sure you call it if you have multiple constructors.
The context instance can be acquired from any view class instances, so you got it covered, because your ListItem extends View.